# Asymmetric behavior of TikZ fadings

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I am a bit confused about the behavior of Ti*k*Z fadings. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}


\newcommand{\FadingQuarterArrowOne}[2][]{
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=#2},#1]
\shade [gray,path fading=south] (-40:1) -- (-40:1.2) arc (-40:40:1.2 and 1.2) --
(40:1.2) --(40:1.3) --
(45:1.1) -- (40:0.9) -- (40:1) arc  (40:-40:1 and 1); 
\end{scope}
}           

\newcommand{\FadingQuarterArrowTwo}[2][]{
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=#2},#1]
\shade [gray,path fading=north] (40:1) -- (40:1.2) arc (40:-40:1.2 and 1.2) --
(-40:1.2) --(-40:1.3) --
(-45:1.1) -- (-40:0.9) -- (-40:1) arc   (-40:40:1 and 1); 
\end{scope}
}           

\begin{document}


\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.south)]{\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=2]{0}}
\hspace*{3cm}
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.south)]{\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=2]{0}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The left arrow is as I expect it to be, it fades away towards the "southern" direction. However, the second arrow, which is just the reverse of the first one, fades away towards the outer regions. I'd like to understand why that happens, and how to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the left case, the shading is from top (gray) to bottom (white). The fading to `south` follows this direction and increases the effect.

In the right case, the shading angle needs to be fixed by `shading angle=180` to get a shading from bottom (gray) to top (white). Then, the effect is increased by fading to `north`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\newcommand{\FadingQuarterArrowOne}[2][]{%
  \begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=#2},#1]
    \shade [gray,path fading=south]
      (-40:1) -- (-40:1.2) arc (-40:40:1.2 and 1.2) --
      (40:1.2) -- (40:1.3) --
      (45:1.1) -- (40:0.9) -- (40:1) arc (40:-40:1 and 1);
  \end{scope}%
}

\newcommand{\FadingQuarterArrowTwo}[2][]{%
  \begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=#2},#1]
    \shade [gray, shading angle=180, path fading=north]
      (40:1) -- (40:1.2) arc (40:-40:1.2 and 1.2) --
      (-40:1.2) -- (-40:1.3) --
      (-45:1.1) -- (-40:0.9) -- (-40:1) arc (-40:40:1 and 1);
  \end{scope}%
}

\begin{document}

\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.south)]{\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=2]{0}}
\hspace*{3cm}
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.south)]{\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=2]{0}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

This works with Acrobat Reader, xpdf, Ghostscript, and Firefox.
But evince 2.32 shows the wrong result, and Google Chrome shows an empty page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Then my interpretation of `path fading=` was incorrect. BTW, it also shows correctly on `preview`, a tool on Mac OS.

Comment: How do you get ghostscript to display anything?

Comment: @cfr Ghostscript was used to generate the image, version is 9.22.

Comment: I guess I just don't get it. Probably just being very dumb.

Comment: @cfr Displaying: `gswin64 test.pdf` or `gswin32 test.pdf` (Windows), `gs test.pdf` (Linux); Conversion, e.g.: `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pnggray -sOutputFile=test.png test.pdf`

Comment: A recent version of evince (3.26) shows the correct result...

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could do that. It doesn't work properly as the window cannot be raised, so is dimmed to near-invisibility. It can be closed, for some reason, but it cannot accept the focus. So I'll have to take your word for it that it displays the result correctly. Interesting, though. (I know about conversion with `gs` and so on - I didn't realise it had any GUI capability.)