# How to properly typeset a rolling r

Tags: typography, fun

To my greatest surprise, LaTeX does not provide any means to properly typeset rolling r's. (OK, neither Word nor pages do any better, but this is hardly a valid criterion.) I am talking here about the forward rolling r as it is spoken in some parts of Italy and the backward rolling r which one can find in parts of Bavaria. It is possible to produce something semi-reasonable with Ti*k*Z,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\newcommand{\FadingQuarterArrowOne}[2][]{% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409185/121799
  \begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=#2},#1]
    \shade [gray,path fading=south]
      (-40:1) -- (-40:1.2) arc (-40:40:1.2 and 1.2) --
      (40:1.2) -- (40:1.3) --
      (45:1.1) -- (40:0.9) -- (40:1) arc (40:-40:1 and 1);
  \end{scope}%
}

\newcommand{\FadingQuarterArrowTwo}[2][]{%
  \begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=#2},#1]
    \shade [gray, shading angle=180, path fading=north]
      (40:1) -- (40:1.2) arc (40:-40:1.2 and 1.2) --
      (-40:1.2) -- (-40:1.3) --
      (-45:1.1) -- (-40:0.9) -- (-40:1) arc (-40:40:1 and 1);
  \end{scope}%
}

\newcommand{\forwardrollingr}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(r.base)]
\node(r){r};
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.15]{0}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.15]{90}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.15]{180}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.15]{270}
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-1mm}
}

\newcommand{\forwardrollingR}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(r.base)]
\node(r){R};
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.2]{0}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.2]{90}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.2]{180}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.2]{270}
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-1mm}
}

\newcommand{\backwardrollingr}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(r.base)]
\node(r){r};
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.15]{0}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.15]{90}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.15]{180}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.15]{270}
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-1mm}
}

\newcommand{\backwardrollingR}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(r.base)]
\node(r){R};
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.2]{0}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.2]{90}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.2]{180}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.2]{270}
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-1mm}
}

\begin{document}

il p\forwardrollingr imo d'ap\forwardrollingr ile

\forwardrollingR isotto

Mu\backwardrollingr meltie\backwardrollingr

\backwardrollingR echenkopf
\end{document}
```

but this appears to be a lot of effort to produce such common characters.

**QUESTION**: Is there a simpler way to make this work?

**ADDENDUM**: @cfr kindly informed me that Welsh also roll the r. (But how should a poor marmot know that, there are no marmots in Wales.) So I can only guess how people there roll their r.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\makeatletter
\def\@anim@@newframe{\@ifstar\@anim@newframe\@anim@newframe}
\def\@anim@newframe{\end{preview}\begin{preview}}
\renewenvironment{animateinline}[2][]{%
  \let\newframe\@anim@@newframe%
  \let\multiframe\@anim@multiframe%
  \begin{preview}}{%
  \end{preview}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
\multiframe{36}{i=0+1}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{sin(\i*10)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{cos(\i*10)}
cute fu\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(b.base),inner sep=0pt]
\node(b){\phantom{rr}};
\node[yscale=\Y,xslant=\X](r){rr};
\end{tikzpicture}y \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(b.base),inner sep=0pt]
\node(b){\phantom{r}};
\node[yscale=\Y,xslant=-\X](r){r};
\end{tikzpicture}odent~~~~~~
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use the R in [Gill’s floriated capitals](http://luc.devroye.org/pape/Misc%20Alphabets/Decorative/Gill%20Canterbury%20Capitals.ttf)  ;-)

Comment: Oh dear.  Well, it’s a free and legal version of [this](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/gill-floriated-caps-mt/).

Comment: Try [this version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jd1egzfspfh75q/GillCanterburyCapitals.otf?dl=0), converted from TTF to OTF by me using FontForge. The R has enough rolling waves to make me sea-sick, but it’s always nice to find a Gill creation in one’s Easter basket!

Comment: You left out Welsh (and some forms of Welsh English). Or is that a deliberate part of the joke? And that is without mentioning 'rh', of course.

Comment: The canonical way to typeset this is shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76316/42 ;-)

Comment: Not an answer, but should both Rs in Murmeltier have the roll?

Comment: @cfr I added something on Welsh way of rolling r's, but this is only guesswork. So I need your input ;-)

Comment: I'm a little confused here, why are people animating the letter? Is it meant to appear like that in text (such as on the web)?

Comment: @DarthPaghius I agree that a non-animated proposal is missing so far.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “forward rolling r” and “backward rolling r”? It sounds like you’re talking about phonetics and pronunciation, but those are not terms that make any sense from a phonetic viewpoint. I’m guessing your forward-rolling r is a regular [alveolar trill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_trills), but what is backward-rolling? A [retroflex approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroflex_approximant) (English r, though that’s usually labialised)? Something else? IPA has characters for all these and many more.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Could you please have a look at (1) the submission date, (2) the first line of the screen shot and (3) the second tag? ;-)

Comment: @marmot Oops—didn’t notice the submission date. Have an upvote instead! \*gently attempts to extricate pedal extremity from oral orifice\*

Comment: @marmot Apparently some marmots are better travelled than others: they certainly (1) [visit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzCShumPtVM) and (2) [give lectures](https://www.cardiff.ac.uk/news/view/1021429-professor-sir-michael-marmot-delivers-the-2017-julian-tudor-hart-lecture).

Comment: @cfr ;-) BTW, what does cfr stand for?

Comment: @marmot If I told you I'd have to kill you and I can't do that because I'm vegan and vegans don't kill marmots.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

How about some more motion?

```
\documentclass[varwidth,multi=page]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\rotateletter[2]{%
  \settoheight\@tempdima{#2}%
  \makebox[\@tempdima]{\hss\rotatebox[origin=c]{#1}{#2}\hss}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {10,20,...,360} {
  \begin{page}
    il p\rotateletter{-\i}{r}imo d'ap\rotateletter{-\i}{r}ile

    \rotateletter{-\i}{R}isotto

    Mu\rotateletter{\i}{r}meltie\rotateletter{\i}{r}

    \rotateletter{\i}{R}echenkopf
  \end{page}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How angry would you be if I accepted the other answer?

Comment: @marmot About [this angry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUS1L.jpg) ;)

Comment: You scare me! ;-)

Answer (score 53):

Marmot's rolling "r"s enhanced with rotating (similar to Menke's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424270/16967)). I tried to reduce the "bumpiness" of the rolling with several methods:

- More precise calculation of the sine and cosine with the `fp` package for the transformation matrix.
- Fix point at TeX level.
- Smaller difference angle.
- Larger resolution.

Colors are added using the `Hsb` color model.

[image: Rolling/rotating letters "r"]

```
[...(see question)...]
\usepackage{fp}    
\newcommand*{\Rot}[2]{%
  \sbox0{#2}%
  \setbox2=\hbox to 0pt{%
    \hss\lower.5\dimexpr\ht0-\dp0\relax\copy0\hss
  }%
  \dp2=0pt\relax
  \ht2=0pt\relax
  \hbox to \wd0{%
    \def\H{#1}%
    \ifdim\H pt<0pt
      \FPadd\H{360}{\H}%
    \fi
    \color[Hsb]{\H,1,1}%
    \hss
    \vrule width 0pt height\ht0 depth\dp0\relax
    \raise.5\dimexpr\ht0-\dp0\relax\hbox{\rotatebox{#1}{\copy2}}%
    \hss
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\NodeRot}[2]{%
  \node(r){\phantom{#2}}
  (r.center) node{%
    \pdfsave
    \FPmul\a{#1}\FPpi
    \FPdiv\a\a{180}%
    \FPcos\c\a
    \FPsin\s\a
    \FPneg\S\s
    \pdfsetmatrix{\c\space\s\space\S\space\c\space}%
    \hbox to 0pt{%
      \hss
      \sbox0{#2}%
      \smash{\lower.5\dimexpr\ht0-\dp0\relax\hbox{#2}}%
      \hss
    }%
    \pdfrestore
  };
}
\newcommand{\forwardrollingr}[1][0]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(r.base)]
\NodeRot{-#1}{r}%
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.15]{0}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.15]{90}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.15]{180}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.15]{270}
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-1mm}
}

\newcommand{\forwardrollingR}[1][0]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(r.base)]
\NodeRot{-#1}{R};
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.2]{0}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.2]{90}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.2]{180}
\FadingQuarterArrowTwo[scale=0.2]{270}
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-1mm}
}

\newcommand{\backwardrollingr}[1][0]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(r.base)]
\NodeRot{#1}{r};
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.15]{0}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.15]{90}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.15]{180}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.15]{270}
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-1mm}
}

\newcommand{\backwardrollingR}[1][0]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(r.base)]
\NodeRot{#1}{R};
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.2]{0}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.2]{90}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.2]{180}
\FadingQuarterArrowOne[scale=0.2]{270}
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-1mm}
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\TEXT}[1][0]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    il p\forwardrollingr[#1]imo d'ap\forwardrollingr[#1] ile
    \\
    \forwardrollingR[#1]isotto
    \\
    Mu\backwardrollingr[#1]meltie\backwardrollingr[#1]
    \\
    \backwardrollingR[#1]echenkopf
  \end{tabular}\newpage
}
\foreach \angle in {0, 3, ..., 359} {
  \TEXT[\angle]
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: These are gorgeous and I am glad this derailed the way it did.

Comment: Is it possible to have the shaded arrows not pixelated?

Comment: @marmot AFAIK the site only supports GIF as animated image format. The number of colors in GIF is limited to 256.

Comment: How angry would you be if I accepted the other answer?

Comment: @marmot Choose whatever you like, it's a [tag:fun] tag anyway.

Comment: Henri Menke had a [more convincing argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUS1L.jpg) ;-) Thanks for joining this fun question!

Answer (score 10):

Not a very fancy solution, but it is simple.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\newcommand{\frR}{\Rconf[R]} %forward rolling R
\newcommand{\frr}{\Rconf[r]} %forward rolling r
\newcommand{\brR}{\Sconf[R]} %backward rolling R
\newcommand{\brr}{\Sconf[r]} %backward rolling r
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={scale=0.75}}
\begin{document}

il p\frr imo d'ap\frr ile

\frR isotto

Mu\brr meltie\brr

\brR echenkopf
\end{document}
```

[image]